# How to differentiate between interface and class from java Class

Tags: java, class, reflection, interface

I have some legacy code that looks like:

```
    Set<Class<? extends Foo>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Foo.class);
    for (Class<? extends Foo> cl : classes) {
        Foo<?, ?> foo = cl.newInstance();
        // use foo
    }
```

I'd like to add another interface:

```
interface NewFoo extends Foo {...}
```

But then it tries to call newInstance on NewFoo. For now my solution is this:

```
        try {
            Foo<?, ?> foo = cl.newInstance();
            // use foo
        } catch (InstantiationException ignore) {
        }
```

but I wonder if there's a better way? Can I differentiate between an interface and a class when I have a Class object in my hand?

Comment: Note also your "solution" would fail for a class without no-args constructor.

Comment: For a long term solution, I recommend to have look at [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) and the underlying concepts. Having to declare the intended implementations may appear less comfortable as an automatic discovery, on the other hand, it doesn’t bear the dangers of automatically using whatever matching class has been found. And it is the only clean solution for getting an instance of an implementation of a different module which is not open for Reflection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call the instance method in Class

```
 clazz.isInterface()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can differentiate if the Class object represents an interface type by calling the method `isInterface()`.

See below:

```
Set<Class<? extends Foo>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Foo.class);
for (Class<? extends Foo> cl : classes) {

    if (! cl.isInterface()) {
        Foo<?, ?> foo = cl.newInstance();
        // use foo
    }
}
```